# Command `hoogle data` fails to download base.txt

Tags: haskell, hoogle

This is the output of `hoogle data`:

```
Downloading downloads/platform.cabal
# platform.cabal (for downloads/platform.cabal)
2015-02-10 19:44:01 URL:http://code.galois.com/darcs/haskell-platform/haskell-platform.cabal [3334/3334] -> downloads/platform.cabal [1]
Downloaded downloads/platform.cabal
Downloading downloads/cabal.tar.gz
# cabal.tar.gz (for downloads/cabal.tar.gz)
2015-02-10 19:44:09 URL:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/index.tar.gz [8794998/8794998] -> downloads/cabal.tar.gz [1]
Downloaded downloads/cabal.tar.gz
# cabal.tar (for downloads/cabal.tar)
Extracting tar file downloads/cabal.index
# cabal.tar (for downloads/cabal.index)
Finished extracting tar file downloads/cabal.index
# cabal.tar (for downloads/cabal.index)
Downloading downloads/hoogle.tar.gz
# hoogle.tar.gz (for downloads/hoogle.tar.gz)
2015-02-10 19:44:38 URL:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hoogle.tar.gz [20734807/20734807] -> downloads/hoogle.tar.gz [1]
Downloaded downloads/hoogle.tar.gz
# hoogle.tar (for downloads/hoogle.tar)
Extracting tar file downloads/hoogle.index
# hoogle.tar (for downloads/hoogle.index)
Finished extracting tar file downloads/hoogle.index
# hoogle.tar (for downloads/hoogle.index)
Downloading downloads/base.txt
# base.txt (for downloads/base.txt)
hoogle: Error when running Shake build system:
* default.hoo
* platform.hoo
* mtl.hoo
* base.txt
* downloads/base.txt.cache
* downloads/base.txt
user error (Development.Shake.command, system command failed
Command: wget -nv --no-check-certificate http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/base.txt --output-document=downloads/base.txt
Exit code: 4
Stderr was empty)
```

Searching on Google didn't yield any useful result. The browser does not resolve http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/base.txt, so I guess it's down? Any workaraounds?

Answer (score 1):

`wget` exit code 4 [indicates a network error](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

The url loads fine in my browser, with a redirect to HTTPS, however.

If you run the `wget` command it's doing directly, do you get any more information?

Comment: Oddly now that I try at home it works well. So I suspect it's a network error on my end! I will be able to try again in three days.